# How to clone a nested map structure with Groovy without blowing up the stack

Tags: json, dictionary, serialization, groovy

I need to cache various data structures in Redis and for performance reasons I'd like to serialize the data as a byte array and store it with BinaryJedis. This seemed like a reasonably simple thing to do until I ran into an issue with some data structures that implement the Map interface, but aren't serializable.

So far I'm dealing with LazyMap and GroovyRowResult, but I'm sure there are others. They're very annoying because the serialization fails silently. If I have a regular map that I've initialized myself it will be a LinkedHashMap and it will serialize nicely. However if my map contains data that I've parsed from JSON or read from SQL then those will be of type LazyMap and GroovyRowResult and they will simply appear as null values in the serialized output.

So I'm writing a recursive function that clones a map structure where all map-type keys are saved as LinkedHashMaps.

This is what I have so far:

```
Closure processMapOrList
processMapOrList = { def data ->
    def processedData = data
    if (data instanceof Map) {
        processedData = [:]
        data.each { entry ->
            processedData[entry.key] = processMapOrList(entry.value)
        }
    } else if (data instanceof Collection) {
        processedData = (data instanceof Set) ? ([] as Set) : []
        data.each { item ->
            processedData << processMapOrList(item)
        }
    }
    processedData
}

processMapOrList(mapOrList)
```

I tried to add trampolining to avoid blowing up the stack, but I noticed that I should rewrite this to use tail calls and I got a bit stuck. I feel like I'm missing some elegant way of doing this, but I just can't see it.

I could store the maps as JSON, but all that parsing seems like a huge waste.